Importing DATEX II file to QGIS
For people familiar with DATEX II (the European XML standard for road traffic and travel information), is there any (easy) way to directly import a layer from a DATEX-structured API to QGIS?
Take for example this API which includes cycleway: DATEX II API example
I have tried to import it as an API without success and also to download it as an XML file but QGIS won't recognize it.

do you have any access to ETL tools (FME, Alteryx etc.)? it would be easier to read and then create into a format QGIS can read (like geopackage)

I could suggest the following workflow. It is based on several Python packages: xml, requests, geopandas, and shapely. It works directly with the DATEX II file from the provided URL: https://fixcyprus.cy/gnosis/open/api/nap/datasets/cycleways/

Proceed with Plugins > Python Console > Show Editor and paste the script below:
# imports
import requests
import geopandas as gpd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from shapely.geometry import LineString
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsProject

# Step 1: downloading the DATE II XML file from the URL
url = "https://fixcyprus.cy/gnosis/open/api/nap/datasets/cycleways/"
response = requests.get(url)
if response.status_code == 200:
    xml_content = response.content
else:
    raise Exception(f"Failed to fetch XML file. HTTP Status Code: {response.status_code}")

# Step 2: parsing the XML content
root = ET.fromstring(xml_content)

# defining namespaces
namespaces = {
    "common": "https://datex2.eu/schema/3/common",
    "linear": "https://datex2.eu/schema/3/linear",
    "location": "https://datex2.eu/schema/3/locationReferencing",
}

# Step 3: extracting the data
data = []
for element in root.findall(path=".//linear:linearElement", namespaces=namespaces):
    # extracting ID and Name
    element_id = element.find(path="common:id", namespaces=namespaces).text
    name_tag = element.find(path=".//common:value", namespaces=namespaces)
    name = name_tag.text if name_tag is not None else "Unknown"

    # extracting coordinates and creating LineString objects
    coordinates = []
    for point in element.findall(path=".//location:pointCoordinates", namespaces=namespaces):
        latitude = float(point.find(path="common:latitude", namespaces=namespaces).text)
        longitude = float(point.find(path="common:longitude", namespaces=namespaces).text)
        coordinates.append((longitude, latitude))  # Note: (longitude, latitude) for GeoDataFrame
    geometry = LineString(coordinates) if coordinates else None

    # appending to the data list
    if geometry:  # Only add entries with valid geometry
        data.append({
            "ID": element_id,
            "Name": name,
            "geometry": geometry,
        })

# Step 4: converting to a GeoDataFrame
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data, crs="EPSG:4326")  # EPSG:4326 is the WGS84 coordinate system

## Optional: saving the GeoDataFrame to a GeoJSON
# gdf.to_file("cycleways.geojson", driver="GeoJSON")  # Save as GeoJSON

# Step 5: adding the GeoDataFrame to the QGIS Project
vl = QgsVectorLayer(gdf.to_json(), "datex2", "ogr")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)


Press Run script  and get the output that will look like:



Note: when working with a file directly on your PC, it is suggested to delete the <style type="text/css">...</style> element, either manually or programmatically. Otherwise, the following error would arise:

xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token):
line 3291, column 99102



References:

Wikipedia | Datex II
Reading Inspire XML with GeoPandas
Loading GeoDataFrame as vector layer without export in QGIS
DATEXII XML file to DataFrame in Python

